# How do I easily find style variables which aren't being used in my React Native app screens within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I know I can go through each screen individually and pull these variables out, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to tell if the style variables are being utilized (even a color change on the variable names similar to when an imported variable isn't being utilized.

This is the kind of color change I want.

[image: This is the kind of color change I want.]

[image: These are the kind of style variables I'm wanting to see a color change on if they are being utilized or not.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a eslint rule `react-native/no-unused-styles`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try and implement this tonight and then if it works I'll mark this as the correct answer to my question :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!